# Reading data in Java

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader

What's the difference between using a `BufferedReader` and a `BufferedInputStream`?

Answer (score 4):

A `BufferedReader` is used for **reading** character data.  A `BufferedOutputStream` is used for **writing** binary data.

Any classes inheriting from [`Reader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) or [`Writer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html) deal with 16-bit unicode character data, whereas classes inherting from [`InputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) or [`OutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) are concerned with processing binary data.  The classes [`InputStreamReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) and [`OutputStreamWriter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html) can be used to bridge between the two classes of data.

Answer (score 3):

Bufferedreader reads data from a file as a string. BufferedOutputStream writes to a file in bytes. BufferedInputStream reads data in bytes
Sample to Bufferedreader:

```
try {
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(your_file));
       while ((thisLine = br.readLine()) != null) { 
         System.out.println(thisLine);
       }
     }
```

Sample to BufferedOutputStream:

```
//Construct the BufferedOutputStream object
        bufferedOutput = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename));

        //Start writing to the output stream
        bufferedOutput.write("Line 1".getBytes());
        bufferedOutput.write("\r\n".getBytes());
        bufferedOutput.write("Line 2".getBytes());
        bufferedOutput.write("\r\n".getBytes());
```

Bufferedinputstream reads in byte:
Sample
:

```
 //Construct the BufferedInputStream object
        bufferedInput = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));

        int bytesRead = 0;


        while ((bytesRead = bufferedInput.read(buffer)) != -1) {                

            String chunk = new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            System.out.print(chunk);
        }
```

Comment: You reference files in your answer but of course the BufferedReader / BufferedOutputStream could be reading from / writing to any destination, not just a file.

Comment: You're right. but just samples to show how he can use... (more practical way to understand)

Answer (score 1):

As the names imply, one is for reading data, and the other is for outputting data.